# How to hide a div when it contains no value with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Good morning all!

I have a little problem with my shopping chart. When a user adds an element to it, the price of the item is displayed without page reload on top of the chart icon. Now I tried wrapping it in a container that I gave a background colour and some padding. that is where my issue comes in. the padding causes the div to be slightly visible before any item is added to it. so I have a little scare at the top of my shopping cart all the time.

I want to hide that div completely when it is empty (when user has not added any item/money to it)

I have come up with this code so far :

HTML

```
<span id ="check">
 <a href="#" class="pjCsCheckout">$70</a>
</span>
```

css

```
#check a {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ddd;
  width:auto;  
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.pjCsCheckout').each(function() {
      if ($.trim($(this).html()) == '')
         $('.pjCsCheckout').hide();
    });
  });
});
```

here is a link to it : http://jsfiddle.net/u1zLbjrn/11/

thank you!!

Comment: Do it with CSS: `#check a:empty {display: none;}`

Comment: this does the job!

Comment: what if there was another block element inside containing the price (not the anchor tag)
example : 
  <span id ="check">
     <a href="#" class="pjCsCheckout">
        <span id="pjCsCartAmount">$70</span>
     </a>
  </span>

i tried the same method and I am unable to hide the span

#check a span:empty {display: none;}

#check a #pjCsCartAmount:empty {display: none;}

Comment: in that case, it only seems to work for me if i change the <span></span> into a <a href="#" id="pjCsCartAmount"></a> . targetiting it with the : #check a:empty {display: none;}

Comment: First, `:empty` doesn't mean visibly empty but empty based on the DOM, that is, it only applies if the element contains nothing at all (with the exception of HTML comments), not even visibly empty text nodes (e.g. line break or white space). Second, your `#check a span:empty` selector should work - use the developer tools to check if the style is applied. But since you have the padding on `#check a`, it has no effect to hide its child element - `a` itself is still visible.

Comment: thank you sir, this solved my problem. I applied the padding to the <span ="pjCsCartamount"></span>

Comment: How do I vote your comment as the solution ???

Comment: Added an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using CSS:

```
#check a:empty {display: none;}
```

Note, however, that `:empty` doesn't mean visibly empty but empty based on the DOM, that is, it only applies if the element contains nothing at all (with the exception of HTML comments), not even visibly empty text nodes (e.g. line break or white space). See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) for more info.

If `#check a` contains a child element, the above style won't work. In this case, you'll have to extend the selector:

```
#check a span:empty {display: none;}
```

Note that this only hides the `span` inside the `a` element and since the padding is on `a`, the above style alone won't solve your problem. You also have to move the padding from `a` to the inner `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd do it:

```
$(function() {
    function divCheck() {
        if ($(".pjCsCheckout").innerHTML == "") {
            $("#check").css("display") = none;
        }
    }
});
```

Call this `divCheck` function inside the `onchange` attribute of all your form elements, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="divCheck()">
```

And it will work!

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply, the comment above you was a simpler solution . I did it with css this way : #check a:empty {display: none;}